# LWC Handling Multiple Dependents @Wire methods

Tags: lightning-web-components, lwc-wire-adapter

How we handle dependent wire in LWC?

For example :

```
  @wire(getObjectInfo, { objectApiName: OPP_OBJECT })
  objectInfo;

  @wire(getPicklistValues, {
    recordTypeId: '$objectInfo.data.defaultRecordTypeId',
    fieldApiName: STATUS_FIELD
  })
  pickListValues;

  @wire(getRecord, { recordId: '$recordId', fields: FIELDS })
  wiredRecord({ error, data }) {
    if (ldsErrorHandling(error) && data) {
      this._status = getFieldValue(data, STATUS_FIELD);
    }
  }
```

I have an operation that depends on the Stage Field of opportunity and also the picklist values. With normal promises or callbacks I can know when the two values are not null. If is a normal apex call we can have both information at the same time. But how we handle this type of situations with `@wire`.

My solution for this (is this the only way?):

```
  @wire(getObjectInfo, { objectApiName: OPP_OBJECT })
  objectInfo;

  @wire(getPicklistValues, {
    recordTypeId: '$objectInfo.data.defaultRecordTypeId',
    fieldApiName: STATUS_FIELD
  })
  handlePickValues({ error, data }) {
    if (ldsErrorHandling(error) && data) {
      this._data = data;
      this.dependentLogic();
    }
  }

  @wire(getRecord, { recordId: '$recordId', fields: FIELDS })
  wiredRecord({ error, data }) {
    if (ldsErrorHandling(error) && data) {
      this._status = getFieldValue(data, STATUS_FIELD);
      this.dependentLogic();
    }
  }

  dependentLogic() {
    if (this._status && this._data) //do logic
  }
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: As far as I can tell you the platform should be able to handle this dependency. Don't know for sure though how. Have you tried this and is there a particular issue that you are facing?

Comment: The issue is, I want to make sure that the two variables are filled before I do my logic. Right now I use in both `getPicklistValues` and `getRecord` with functions instead putting directly in a var. Inside the function I call a method. On top of this method I verify if both var are not null, and then I do the logic. I don't like this approach, and I like to know exactly what my code is doing.

Comment: +1 to @JayantDas's answer: the code you provide _should_ work. If it doesn't please post the minimal code that fails with details of the error.

@wire (like Promises) operates asynchronously. You must coordinate their resolution. You can do this with a simple check. Eg `if (this.objectInfo.data && this.picklistValue.data) { ... }`

Comment: Hello @KevinVenkiteswaran, the code always worked. My only doubt was that with `@wire` the only way I know is to call two or more times(depending how many dependencies) the same function and check if all values that we need is not null. And I was asking if has a better way to do.

Comment: @EliasPinheiro Did you get any solution, what you did at last, I've the same scenario, I don't want to create dependency on the wired services and having a business logic which dependent on two different wired service output.

Answer (score 12):

According to LWC docs:

> The component’s JavaScript prefaces the value of the objectInfo parameter with $ to indicate that it’s dynamic and reactive. It references a property of the component instance. If its value changes, the template rerenders.

Before understanding `dynamic and reactive` variable lets understand `reactive` (that is , track).

When track variable is re-assigned/changed in Javascript, LWC will re-render the DOM with updated track variables.

What will happen if `dynamic ('$objectInfo')` changes?

Well, the wire functions dependent on this variable is triggered.

> So, change in dynamic '$objectInfo' will trigger the Javascript functions which are dependent on it. IMPORTANT: this will not re-render DOM.
>
> objectInfo is made both dynamic and reactive by using it as `$objectInfo` and also decorating it with track.

So, below code will work:

```
  @wire(getObjectInfo, { objectApiName: OPP_OBJECT })
  objectInfo;

  @wire(getPicklistValues, {
    recordTypeId: '$objectInfo.data.defaultRecordTypeId',
    fieldApiName: STATUS_FIELD
  })
  pickListValues;
```

**Reason:** Here second wire will be triggered ONLY after first wire updates `objectInfo`. Thus `pickListValues` will be updated after getting `objectInfo`

> **Best practice:** Do not use '$dynamic' variables in HTML (by decorating as track). Because if you are decorating this dynamic variable as track, 1st it will rerender the DOM
>   before wire is triggered and again after wire gets the data, DOM is
>   rerendered again (leading to performance degradation due to twice rerender of DOM). You can verify this with rerenderedCallback.

---

**Important Notes:** https://salesforcesas.home.blog/2019/07/23/dynamic-and-reactive-javascript-class-properties-in-lwc-track-wire-and/

Comment: Are you sure that it will trigger that way?

Comment: YES! Tested it here: https://salesforcesas.home.blog/2019/07/23/dynamic-and-reactive-javascript-class-properties-in-lwc-track-wire-and/

Comment: Hello @salesforcesas, thank you very much for your answer, but I think you did not understand what I asked. I have two wire methods that has no dependencies in each other. But I have business logic that depends on both. And if I made the two wire dependent they will get data in serialized mode that is slower than parallel requests.

Comment: When your business logic is dependent on 2 different apex calls, then you should be using imperative function calls (not wired props/functions) and you should use Promise.all([apexFunction1(),apexFunction2()]);

Comment: If I use getRecord in an imperative way I will lose the reactivity of the wire in the lightning data service. But for other things it will be the best choice for sure.

Comment: @EliasPinheiro did you find any way to handle this imperatively without losing reactivity?

Answer (score 4):

I had similar requirements. What I decided to do is to have @track property and pass it as a parameter to @wire method.

```
@track
objectInfo;
@wire(getObjectInfo, { objectApiName: OPP_OBJECT })
setObjectInfo({error, data}) {
    if (data) {
        this.objectInfo = data;
    } else if (error) {
        // ...
    }
}

@wire(getPicklistValues, {
    recordTypeId: '$objectInfo.data.defaultRecordTypeId',
    fieldApiName: STATUS_FIELD
})
pickListValues;
```

So when `this.objectInfo` is set, then `getPicklistValues` is called.

Comment: Hello @ytiq, thank you very much for your answer, but I think you did not understand what I asked. I have two wire methods that has no dependencies in each other. But I have business logic that depends on both. And if I made the two wire dependent they will get data in serialized mode that is slower than parallel requests.

Answer (score 2):

Addressing this from the perspective of having logic that is dependent on two wire calls (and not a wire method that depends on another, which has already been answered), an alternative to using a common function call is to put the dependent logic into a common getter:

```
@wire(getObjectInfo, { objectApiName: OPP_OBJECT })
objectInfo;

@wire(getPicklistValues, {
    recordTypeId: "$objectInfo.data.defaultRecordTypeId",
    fieldApiName: STATUS_FIELD
})
handlePickValues({ error, data }) {
    if (ldsErrorHandling(error) && data) {
        this._data = data;
    }
}

@wire(getRecord, { recordId: "$recordId", fields: FIELDS })
wiredRecord({ error, data }) {
    if (ldsErrorHandling(error) && data) {
        this._status = getFieldValue(data, STATUS_FIELD);
    }
}

get dependentResult() {
    let result;
    if(this._status && this._data) {
        //Process logic based on results from both wires. 
    }
    return result;
}
```

Then you can use this.dependentResult elsewhere in your component.