# Apex method not getting invoked in LWC

Tags: apex, lightning, lightning-web-components, lwc-wire-adapter

LWC JS:

```
import { LightningElement, api, wire, track } from 'lwc';
import getAccDetails from '@salesforce/apex/UI_Controller.getAccountName';
export default class AccordionComp extends LightningElement {
@wire(getAccDetails, { accId: 'Account_Details', parent: '$recordId' }) accDetails(result) {

        if (result.data) {
            console.log('Check output');
            console.log(this.result);
        }
        console.log('before callout');
    }
}
```

APex:

```
public with sharing class UI_Controller {
@AuraEnabled (Cacheable = true)
    public static String getAccountName(String accId,String parent) {
        System.debug('$$'+accId);
        return 'Hello World';

    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, and welcome to SFSE! Please take a moment read about [ask], then [edit] your question to include any additional relevant information. As it is, we don't know what the problem is, and there's no immediately obvious reason why it wouldn't work. Do you get any errors? Did you check debug logs? Is there any additional information we can use to help you?

Comment: I have a few thoughts- but first could you provide some more details? Are any of your log statements printing anything (apex or javascript), are you getting any error messages, how is this Lwc being used, etc. Let's start there and then I can help you troubleshoot with more context

Comment: Not sure what you’re use case is, but you haven’t even defined a “recordId” property in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Behaviour of wired function:

1. It will run for the first time to register wired method where you will get `result {data: undefined, error: undefined}`
2. Next time onwards, wired function will execute and invoke apex method ONLY when none of the parameters are `undefined`.
3. If wired function is dependent on `dynamic` property like `$recordId`, then it will execute and invoke apex method only when dynamic property changes and not `undefined`.

**In your case its not invoking because `recordId` is `undefined` and you are never changing it.**

For testing this, you can implement below connectedCallback:

```
connectedCallback() {
    this.recordId = undefined; // will NOT run since undefined
    setTimeout(() => (this.recordId = 'some id'), 1000); // will run
    setTimeout(() => (this.recordId = 'some other id'), 2000); // will run
    setTimeout(() => (this.recordId = 'some other id'), 3000); // will NOT run since no change in recordId
    setTimeout(() => (this.recordId = undefined), 4000); // will NOT run since undefined although changed
    setTimeout(() => (this.recordId = null), 5000); // will run for null
    setTimeout(() => (this.recordId = 'undefined'), 6000); // will run 
}
```

Given in the comments above when it will execute and not execute.

**NOTE:** `$` dynamic property is automatically declared. No need of separate declaration in class.

Comment: None of this would work.... the OP doesn’t have a variable defined for this.

Comment: @SebastianKessel. Not really needed. `$` makes it dynamic (and automatically declared/defined) - on which wire will be dependent. If you also define it as `track`, it makes it reactive. Both are not interdependent. For detailed explanation, you can check this: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/260135/lwc-handling-multiple-dependents-wire-methods?atw=1.... Detailed explanation - https://salesforcesas.home.blog/2019/07/23/dynamic-and-reactive-javascript-class-properties-in-lwc-track-wire-and/

Comment: RecordId was the issue and it's working, It was a small mistake from my side, trying to execute it in Ltng App rather than on the corresponding record page. Thanks for the detailed explanation @salesforce-sas

Comment: @RamP its actually not a mistake. I think you got confused as it always runs 1st time when registering giving undefined.